# Value becomes undefined when passing between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with nodejs as server-side for my react app, I want to send an array of names of files in directory with Root_Path value . I use readdir () to take names and put them into List_Of_File .

```
fs.readdir(Root_Path, 'utf8', (err, files) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  else
    files.forEach(element => {
      List_Of_File.push(element.split(".")[0]);
    });
});


List_Of_File.forEach(element => {
  List_Of_Note.push(element);
});

fs.readdir(Root_Path, 'utf8', (err, files) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  else
    files.forEach(element => {
      List_Of_File.push(element.split(".")[0]);
    });
});


List_Of_File.forEach(element => {
  List_Of_Note.push(element);
});

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(List_Of_File);
```

and I got result which is `["3","4","5"]`

but when I try to pass all values to `List_Of_Note`, the values are undefined and I got result which is [] when I send `List_Of_Note`.

I check the type of value in `List_Of_File` which is a string.
Can you help me solve this?

Comment: Why u r looping unnecessarily for `List_Of_File` for `List_Of_Note`. From your code both are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fs.readdir(Root_Path, 'utf8', (err, files) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  else
    files.forEach(element => {
      List_Of_File.push(element.split(".")[0]);
    });
});


List_Of_File.forEach(element => {
  List_Of_Note.push(element);
});
```

These two set of lines are not synchronous. You will have to wait till callback is called for `readdir` method. Since you are not waiting, you are always getting empty array. You can move pushing logic inside the callback or convert this in a promise/async/await based.